# How to syndicate to a slack channel?

Tags: rss, feed, slack

I know that I can syndicate to a feed, so that the feed will spit out in a slack channel.
But can I use an RSS-feed software to syndicate Slack channels?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work out-of-the-box since Slack Channels are private to your team and RSS feeds are public. But you could develop an adapter that exposes all messages in a Slack channel with an RSS feed.

The adapter could use an [outgoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) to get all messages from a Slack Channel, buffer the data from Slack and then have a RSS feeder interface that provides the data to a consumer in RSS format.

There may already be existing adapters on the web. I would suggest looking on Github, before developing a new one.